# datatable no soporta "\r\n" o quitar salto de linea en textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

DATATABLE 10.11.16 no funciona si un campo de texto tiene  `"\r\n"` saltos de linea dice jason error

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/Listar_notas.php',

    },
    columns: [ ... ]
} );
```

abra alguna solución para esto.

o lo otro que se me ocurre es quitar los espacios en blanco de  que esta apunto de ingresar a la base de datos.

probé haciendo esto pero igual me sigue ingresando saltos de linea. yo quiero que todo quede en una sola linea si hago esto

```
$campo_obs = str_replace("\r\n","<br>",$textarea);
```

abra alguna configuracion para datatable o me podrian ayudar a quitar los saltos de linea para una sola linea

Answer (score 0):

Pruebalo de esta manera:

```
$campo_obs = str_replace("\r\n"," ",$textarea);
```

Asi te quedará en una sola línea ya que la la etiqueta `<br>` es la que te está ingresando el salto de línea.